# How to make the full million value show up on y-axis and tooltip (Highcharts)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have been messing with this for a while now and have no clue why nothing will take when I try to format this data set for millions. Any insight please let me know, might just be that I am not seeing a really simple part. I went through the Highcharts docs and nothing I tried with formatter or anything else worked. So i stripped out my edits and added the code below as it was before I changed it.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4d3vnfgt/)

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Industry $',
        style: {

                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'By Year',
        style: {

                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Open Sans, sans-serif',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        labels: {

            format: '{value}',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            },

        rotation: 0,
        style: {

                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Total $',
            style: {

                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        }

    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'Total $: <b>{point.y}</b>',

    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Population',
        data: [
            ['2005', 25,000],
            ['2006', 50,000],
            ['2007', 75,000],
            ['2008', 98,000],
            ['2009', 200,000],
            ['2010', 600,000],
            ['2011', 800,000],
            ['2012', 1,000,000]
        ],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
             tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        },
            rotation: 0,
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'center',
            format: '{point.y}', // one decimal
            y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }

        }
    }]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the commas out

e.g.

```
data: [
        ['2005', 25,000],
        ['2006', 50,000],
        ['2007', 75,000],
        ['2008', 98,000],
        ['2009', 200,000],
        ['2010', 600,000],
        ['2011', 800,000],
        ['2012', 1,000,000]
    ],
```

should be:

```
data: [
        ['2005', 25000],
        ['2006', 50000],
        ['2007', 75000],
        ['2008', 98000],
        ['2009', 200000],
        ['2010', 600000],
        ['2011', 800000],
        ['2012', 1000000]
    ],
```

Comment: Thanks, still need to add comma's also, but I am sure I can get that figured out.